# Redis HINCRBY overwriting data inside redlocked transaction

Tags: node.js, redis, transactions

I have a function that updates a user balance by a certain amount:

```
export function incrementUsersOpenOrderBalance(order, amount, multi) {
  multi.hincrby('order_sums', `${order.GetUserId()}-${order.coin}`, amount)
}
```

that works perfectly 99% of the time. It is inside a redlock:

```
    try {
      lock = await rateLock.lock(`locks:balance:${userId}`, 60000)
      let userBalance = await balancestore.getBalanceForUserId(userId)
      do {
        let multi = redis.multi();
        executedTrades = await placeOrder(orderProcessing, userBalance, multi)
        await completeTradesInTransaction(executedTrades, execMulti)
      } while (1);
    } catch(e) {
       ...
    } finally {
      if (lock) {
        lock.unlock()
        lock = null
      }
    }
```

(`execMulti`) is calling `await multi.execAsync()`

There is a lot of logic inside, but user balance is only updated once per call. For some reason, it occasionally will not `HINCRBY -XXXXXXX` and decrement by the correct amount. I've noticed a trend every time it happens, it actually runs this `HINCRBY -XXXXXXX` command, then the next order processes, and then the user balance is actually SET to `-XXXXXXX`. I am guessing it happens during the `HINCRBY -XXXXXXX` call, where it actually overwrites the value instead of updating it.

I have run `redis-cli MONITOR` to  watch this several times, and the weird thing is that everything looks fine to me.

```
1543351721.451263 [0 lua] "set" "locks:balance:userid" "random_value" "NX" "PX" "60000"
1543351721.473371 [0 10.56.5.109:47958] "multi"
1543351721.473533 [0 10.56.5.109:47958] "hincrby" "order_sums" "userid" "-2483395200000"
1543351721.473598 [0 10.56.5.109:47958] "hincrby" "sums" "order-sum" "-3520000"
1543351721.473635 [0 10.56.5.109:47958] "exec"
1543351721.483502 [0 lua] "get" "locks:balance:userid"
1543351721.483543 [0 lua] "del" "locks:balance:userid"
1543351721.485265 [0 lua] "set" "locks:balance:userid" "new_random_value" "NX" "PX" "60000"
1543351721.501101 [0 10.56.5.109:47958] "multi"
1543351721.501331 [0 10.56.5.109:47958] "hincrby" "sums" "order_sum" "-3910000"
1543351721.501376 [0 10.56.5.109:47958] "hincrby" "order_sums" "userid" "-2758544100000"
1543351721.501507 [0 10.56.5.109:47958] "exec"
1543351721.503079 [0 lua] "get" "locks:balance:userid"
1543351721.503104 [0 lua] "del" "locks:balance:userid"
```

As you can see, it locks each time, then begins a transaction with `MULTI`, performs the hincrby, then `EXEC`, then releases the lock.

After this, I have it publish balances, and the `userid` balance is set to `-2483395200000`. I have noticed this behavior multiple times.

Basically `HINCRBY` is very rarely overwriting the data instead of updating it.

Comment: Are you sure that the "userid" field in the "order_sums" hash exists when you call HINCRBY? If it doesn't, it is implicitly created and initialized to 0, which would explain what you're seeing.

Comment: Yep. Upon further investigation, it looks like the data is actually being corrupted somewhere instead of the math being wrong. I've been trying to isolate a case that reproduces it so as to write a test for it.